# idiomatic alternative to choose -> test -> value-of (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In the work I do I seem to see a lot of code liek this..

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="long_xpath_to_optional/@value1">
      <xsl:value-of select="long_xpath_to_optional/@value"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="another_long_xpath_to_optional/@value">
      <xsl:value-of select="another_long_xpath_to_optional/@value"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <etc>
   </etc>
   <otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="default_long_xpath_to_value"/>
   </otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

its very long and very repetitive.

When I'm were working in some other (psuedo) language I would go

```
let values = concat(list(long_xpath_to_optional_value),list(another_long_xpath_to_optional_value))
let answer = tryhead(values,default_long_xpath_to_value)
```

i.e. create a list of values in priority order, and then take the head.
I only evaluate each path once

how would you do something similar in XSLT 1.0 (we can use node-sets).

Comment: It is possible to use variables but forming a list or rather sequence to then select the head requires XPath 2; unless the three values have the same document order as your priority order , then you could use the `|` union `(exp1 | exp2 | exp3)[1]`

Comment: using variables means, assigning the value to a variable? then testing it? then if its present evaluating it?

Comment: I have tried to show the concept of variables in an answer as it is easier to format code snippets there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if you can create a node-set somehow

You can - but it's not going to be any shorter:

```
<xsl:variable name="values">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="long_xpath_to_optional/@value" mode="values"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="another_long_xpath_to_optional/@value" mode="values"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="default_long_xpath_to_value/@value" mode="values"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($values)/value[1]" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>
```

and then:

```
<xsl:template match="@value" mode="values">
    <value>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </value>
</xsl:template>
```

But at least the repetition is eliminated.

---

Alternatively, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="@value" mode="values">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

and then:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($values, '|')"/>
```

Comment: hmmm....it is what I asked for....the question is, is it sufficiently better to outweigh the weirdness

Comment: That is not for me to judge - esp. when I don't see the full picture. Perhaps there is a 3rd option.

Comment: well, thats why I was asking for an idiomatic approach, you would have thought it happens all the time

Comment: tbh, I'd drop the template "values", and simply embed all the values in a set of "<value>"s....I'll give that a go

Comment: That's not the same thing. Do note that in your original code, when a node exists but is empty, the result will be empty. In your proposed method, you won't be able to distinguish between missing and empty.

Comment: As for "idiomatic", I prefer "best for the given situation" - and that's difficult to determine without knowing what the given situation is.

Comment: ah I see...if they don't exist, then the template isnt invoked!

Answer (score 0):

To use variables you write

```
<xsl:variable name="value1" select="long_xpath_to_optional/@value1"/>
<xsl:variable name="value2" select="another_long_xpath_to_optional/@value"/>
<xsl:variable name="value3" select="default_long_xpath_to_value"/>
```

and then in XPath 2 or 3 all you would need is `($value1, $value2, $value3)[1]` or `head(($value1, $value2, $value3))` but in XSLT 1 with XPath 1 all you can write as a single expression is `($value1 | $value2 | $value3)[1]` which sorts in document order so unless the document order is the same as your test order this wouldn't work to check the values; rather you would need to maintain the

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$value1">
      <xsl:value-of select="$value1"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="$value2">
      <xsl:value-of select="$value2"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$value3"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Of course in XPath 2 you wouldn't really need the variables and could use `(long_xpath_to_optional/@value1, another_long_xpath_to_optional/@value, default_long_xpath_to_value)[1]` as well directly.

Comment: ah ok, yes....I was wondering if you can create a node-set somehow

Comment: The union operator gives you a node-set, but in document order.